# Excel - vlookup with multiple conditions

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to do a lookup in Excel based on the following.
Situation - I want to look up what the speed limit is in a given section of road.

Essentially the table I'm looking up specifies that the speed limit is, say, 50, from road position 0-123, then 60 from road position 123-500. The table has road_id, start_pos, end_pos, speedlimit.

On another sheet, roadid and position are entered.

I want to lookup 'speedlimit' from the row where roadid=road_id AND position>start_pos AND position

I have tried the following but Excel doesn't like the greater than / less than signs.

```
=INDEX(speed limit column,MATCH(roadid&<position&>position,road_id&start_pos&end_pos,0)
```

Comment: It would be very helpful if you'd post a screenshot of your sheet, or upload the document for anyone willing to help to take a look at what you have Exactly. Also, after that, write out in pseudo-code what you would like to happen (e.g. With variables road_id, position, start, end, lookup the id in a table and give me X).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't enter complex expression in `MATCH`, use `SUMIFS` or `AVERAGEIFS` (as you're looking for one value both will give the same result):

`=SUMIFS (speed limit column, road id column, road_id,start pos column, "<=" & position, end pos column, ">" & position)`